# regularized incomplete beta function integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, mathematica, beta-function

Solve $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{I_{u^{\frac{1}{p}}}\left ( p+\frac{1}{a} ,1-\frac{1}{a}\right )}{u}du$ . In Mathematica, this integral does not converge but from an article, I got the answer to this integral as $\frac{a^{2}}{(pa+1)^{2}*\beta (p+\frac{1}{a},1-\frac{1}{a})}*3F2\left (p+\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{a},p+\frac{1}{a};p+\frac{1}{a}+1,p+\frac{1}{a}+1;1 \right )$. Is this answer correct, if so how can I solve the above integral.